# Не работает анимация крестика

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, svg

```css
.ham {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  transition: transform 400ms;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.hamRotate.active {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.hamRotate180.active {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.line {
  fill:none;
  transition: stroke-dasharray 400ms, stroke-dashoffset 400ms;
  stroke:#000;
  stroke-width:5.5;
  stroke-linecap:round;
}
.ham1 .top {
  stroke-dasharray: 40 139;
}
.ham1 .bottom {
  stroke-dasharray: 40 180;
}
.ham1.active .top {
  stroke-dashoffset: -98px;
}
.ham1.active .bottom {
  stroke-dashoffset: -138px;
}
```

```html
<svg class="ham hamRotate ham1  " viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="80"  onclick="this.classList.toggle('active')" >
     onclick="this.classList.toggle(' active')"
  <path
        class="line top"
        d="m 30,33 h 40 c 0,0 9.044436,-0.654587 9.044436,-8.508902 0,-7.854315 -8.024349,-11.958003 -14.89975,-10.85914 -6.875401,1.098863 -13.637059,4.171617 -13.637059,16.368042 v 40" />
  <path
        class="line middle"
        d="m 30,50 h 40" />
  <path
        class="line bottom"
        d="m 30,67 h 40 c 12.796276,0 15.357889,-11.717785 15.357889,-26.851538 0,-15.133752 -4.786586,-27.274118 -16.667516,-27.274118 -11.88093,0 -18.499247,6.994427 -18.435284,17.125656 l 0.252538,40" />
</svg>
```

Но мне надо что бы при нажатии на другую кнопку срабатывала анимация для этого пишу

`$('#filter-menu-button').click(function(){
  $('.hamRotate').toggleClass("active");
});`
Но не работает

Comment: на какую кнопку ??

Comment: Добавьте в пример кнопку которая должна быть и что не получается.

Comment: @Nilsan   на любую кнопку.Просто можно создать дефолтную кнопку и  при нажатии на эту кнопку происходит анимация

Comment: @Избытоксусликов на любую кнопку.Просто можно создать дефолтную кнопку и  при нажатии на эту кнопку происходит анимация

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery может работать с SVG [только](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10257755/7678419) с версии 3+.
Вы можете изменить `.toggleClass()` на `.attr()` или использовать `.classList.toggle()`. Ниже пример кода с решением через `.classList.toggle()`

```js
function toggleButton() {
  document.querySelector('.hamRotate').classList.toggle('active');
}

document.querySelector('.hamRotate').addEventListener('click', toggleButton, false);
document.querySelector('#filter-menu-button').addEventListener('click', toggleButton, false);
```

```css
.ham {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  transition: transform 400ms;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.hamRotate.active {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.hamRotate180.active {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  transition: stroke-dasharray 400ms, stroke-dashoffset 400ms;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 5.5;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}

.ham1 .top {
  stroke-dasharray: 40 139;
}

.ham1 .bottom {
  stroke-dasharray: 40 180;
}

.ham1.active .top {
  stroke-dashoffset: -98px;
}

.ham1.active .bottom {
  stroke-dashoffset: -138px;
}
```

```html
<svg class="ham hamRotate ham1  " viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="80">
  <path
        class="line top"
        d="m 30,33 h 40 c 0,0 9.044436,-0.654587 9.044436,-8.508902 0,-7.854315 -8.024349,-11.958003 -14.89975,-10.85914 -6.875401,1.098863 -13.637059,4.171617 -13.637059,16.368042 v 40" />
  <path
        class="line middle"
        d="m 30,50 h 40" />
  <path
        class="line bottom"
        d="m 30,67 h 40 c 12.796276,0 15.357889,-11.717785 15.357889,-26.851538 0,-15.133752 -4.786586,-27.274118 -16.667516,-27.274118 -11.88093,0 -18.499247,6.994427 -18.435284,17.125656 l 0.252538,40" />
</svg>

<button id="filter-menu-button">Push me !</button>
```